# How to provide return_url to SetupIntent when creating a new Stripe subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments

When I'm creating a new trialing subscription with a card that requires additional SCA authentication, a pending SetupIntent object is [automatically created](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#using-setupintents). Its status equals `requires_action` which means it's already been confirmed and waits for SCA authentication flow to be completed (using Stripe.js's `handleCardSetup()`).

I need some way to specify redirection `return_url` to the SetupIntent so that the user could be redirected back to my application from SCA authentication site. The problem is that according to the docs I can specify `return_url` to the SetupIntent either at creation or [confirmation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/confirm?lang=java#confirm_setup_intent), however by the time the subscription has been created, the pending SetupIntent object is already confirmed.

So how can I specify the `return_url`? Is there possibly a way to do that before I create the subscription?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, Stripe does not let you modify the `return_url` property of a `PaymentIntent` or `SetupIntent` that was automatically created by their Billing product.

In this case, you have to do the automatic confirmation flow and can't control the redirect step. This shouldn't be a problem though as your customers are on your page at that point and you can always submit to your server after a success and keep the webhook solution as a fallback to catch cases where the customer closed their browser before they reached your redirect URL.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! So do you mean that my customers always stay on my page because `handleCardSetup()` is always supposed to be running inside of an iframe? At least this is what I see while running the testing SCA flow.

Comment: Correct! With 3D Secure 2.0 the authentication happens on the page and shouldn't need a redirect.